# Rotate left the last 10 bits in an int

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, byte-shifting

I need to implement a function that rotates left the last 10 bits of an int.

So if an int has value

```
0b 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 1100 0000
```

a left rotation by 2 would give us

```
0b 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 0000 0000
```

A further left rotation by 1 would give

```
0b 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 1110 0000 0001
```

- `ptr` - pointer to given int that we want to rotate
- `n` - how many times we want to rotate

```
void leftRotateLast10Digits(int * ptr, int n) {

}
```

I understand how to do it if we wanted to rotate the whole int, but I'm not sure how to do it for the last 10 digits only. I think to left rotate an int, it would look something like below. But still, I don't understand how to only rotate the last 10 digits.

```
void leftRotate(int * ptr, int n) {
    int DROPPED_MSB;
    int INT_BITS = sizeof(int) * 8 - 1;
    int num = *ptr;

    // The effective rotation
    n %= INT_BITS;

    while(n) {
        DROPPED_MSB = (num >> INT_BITS) & 1; 

        // Left rotate num by 1 and set its dropped MSB as new LSB
        num = (num << 1) | DROPPED_MSB;
        n--;
    }
    *ptr = num;
}
```

Comment: You could take the starting number and & it with 0b1111111111111111111110000000000. Now you have the bits that must not change. You can do the inverse and & the starting number with 0b1111111111. Those 10 bits need to rotate. You know how to do that. Finally | the both numbers together.

Comment: 1) so the rotation involves only the 10 least significant bits, did I understand correctly? 2) `int INT_BITS = sizeof(int) * 8 - 1;` seem to build a general function working for every architecture. Is it a requirement? Would the assumption of a 4byte integer acceptable?

Comment: scy17, do you want this rotation to work for `n > 9`, for `n < 0`?

Comment: scy17 Note: `int INT_BITS = sizeof(int) * 8 - 1;   n %= INT_BITS;` is questionable code.  I'd expect `n %= INT_BITS + 1;` and more to handle `n < 0`.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm not sure how to do it for the last 10 digits only

Isolate the 10 bits from the rest.

Rotate the 10 bits (I'd skip the `while` loop).

"Or" the 10 bits back into the `int`.

---

(Let us use "least" rather than "last")

```
void leftRotateLeast10Digits(int *ptr, int n) {
  int value = *ptr;
  int ls10bits = value & 0x3FF;
  value ^= ls10bits;  // zero out the 10 LS bits.
  
  // If `n` outside [0...9] range needed
  n %= 10;
  if (n < 0) n += 10;

  // move LS bits left `n` times` and MS bits right `10-n` times.
  int rotated = (ls10bits << n) | (ls10bits >> (10-n));
  rotated &= 0x3FF;

  value |= rotated;
  *ptr = value;
}
```

---

Some additional work needed to support 16-bit `int`.  `int ls10bits` --> `int_least32_t ls10bits` to easily handle the `<<`.
I'd suggest this also works for rare non-2's complement when the result is not a trap.

---

Tip: bit manipulations and shifts are best done with *unsigned* types and math rather than *signed* ones like `int`.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively easy way to do this would be to separate the integer into two parts: the 10 bits that should be rotated and the other (upper) bits that shouldn't be rotated. Then, after rotating the appropriate part, restore the other bits using a bitwise OR operation:

```c
void leftRotate(int* ptr, int n)
{
    int mask = 0x03FF; // Mask for lower 10 bits;
    int DROPPED_MSB;
    int INT_BITS = 10; // Only work with 10 bits
    int num = *ptr & mask; // Extract JUST low 10 bits
    int top = *ptr & ~mask; // Save all the OTHER bits
    n %= INT_BITS; // The effective rotation
    while (n) {
        DROPPED_MSB = (num >> INT_BITS) & 1;
        // Left rotate num by 1 and set its dropped MSB as new LSB
        num = (num << 1) | DROPPED_MSB;
        n--;
    }
    *ptr = num | top; // Restore the saved upper bits
}
```